# undefined an index error in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

my file api upload using ajax got an undefined index error in php

this is my partial js

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = tempW;
canvas.height = tempH;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'upload.php');

          request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var data = 'SelectedFile=' + dataURL;

  request.send(data);
          console.log(data);
```

full code can be viewed here : http://jsfiddle.net/q99ek/1/

this is the result of console.log(data) `SelectedFile=data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMD…pgetFFfPS3PTnBRjoPiLHoaleQlFTvmiismrs6oSfsbF6KM+WMHGKsRAZxRRXFM7sP8KP/2Q==`

but in my php file I tried

var_dump($_POST['']);
var)dump($_FILE['SelectedFile'];
both returned null.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` (without `['']`) - does it show anything?

Comment: Did you meant [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) ?

Comment: @user1781026I got array (size=1)  'SelectedFile' => string 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCAEsAO0DASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1'... (length=40171)

Comment: @user3398172 Your `$_POST['SelectedFile']` doesn't seem to be empty, next try `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: @user1781026 array (size=0)  empty

Comment: I seem like I have to use $_POST